# Add XML attribute or element to a collection element using serialization

Tags: c#, collections, xml-serialization, xml-attribute, xmlelement

How should my class look like to serialize to/from a XML like this

```
<root>
   <MyCollection ColDetails="val1">
      <Col_Obj>
          <Prop1>xxxx</Prop1>
          <Prop2>xxxx</Prop2>
      </ColObj>
      <Col_Obj>
          <Prop1>xxxx</Prop1>
          <Prop2>xxxx</Prop2>
      </ColObj>
   </MyCollection>
</root>
```

*...this one -> `ColDetails="val1"`*

or

```
<root>
   <MyCollection>
      <ColDetails>val1</ColDetails>
      <Col_Obj>
          <Prop1>xxxx</Prop1>
          <Prop2>xxxx</Prop2>
      </ColObj>
      <Col_Obj>
          <Prop1>xxxx</Prop1>
          <Prop2>xxxx</Prop2>
      </ColObj>
   </MyCollection>
</root>
```

*...this one -> `<ColDetails>val1</ColDetails>`*

C# Class

```
  public string ColDetails { get; set; }

  public List<Col_Obj> MyCollection { get; set; }

  public class Col_Obj
  {
      public string Prop1 { get; set; }
      public string Prop2 { get; set; }
  }
```

Prefer to serialize with `System.Xml.Serialization`.

I can easily specify two properties as an XML attribute with value using `[XmlAttribute]` and `[XmlText]`, that's half the way I assume?

Comment: You can paste your XML into [Xml2Csharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) and it will generate classes for you. You've got some mismatched tags - `Col_Obj` vs `ColObj` but once I got past that it worked.

Comment: It just make one-to-one XML's without collections etc, so it not of much use, at least not for creation classes to be use for serialization of dynamic data-sets.